# How to handle user dbs after migrating system databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Due to an unrecoverable OS crash I have installed sql server (same edition as source server) on a new machine and then restored the system dbs.

When I start the sql server I can see all linked servers, agent jobs, logins, but the user dbs aren't accessible because their mdf/ldf is missing.

How to handle this scenario?

Option 1: Delete the user dbs from the SSMS and then restore them from backups (I loose 1 day data because we have nightly full backups)

Option 2: Copy the mdf/ldf files into the respective drives (no data loss)

Option 3: Delete user dbs, copy mdf/ldf, attach

What are the risks with option 2 and option 3?

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is simpler, but all the data files must be put in the same locations they were on the old server.  If you run into trouble with 2, revert to 3, and then if necessary, to 1.

Comment: Can't find any Microsoft documentation about this server migration or DR approach. Is there any documentation about this? The most closest documentation is the upgrade by presenting disk approach given at the end of this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/choose-a-database-engine-upgrade-method?view=sql-server-ver16